# Awkward Font Rendering On Chromium Based Browsers

Tags: css, fonts, google-font-api

I am using the Google Font - `Varela Round` available here - [Varela Round](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Varela+Round)

Things were fine but of late I see awkward 'extra tall' alphabets rendered on Chromium based browsers like Chrome and Opera. Though things are perfect on Non-Chromium browsers like Firefox and IE.

[image: Chromium Based Browsers] - Chromium Based Browsers

[image: Non-Chromium Based Browsers] - Non-Chromium Based Browsers

How can fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

This problem could be caused by a lot of reasons the most famous one is that some browsers in your case here chromium based browsers could be adding extra CSS so try adding a reset.css file like [this one](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

and may be try creating a code pen if this answer does not work for you so others can debug and find out your exact problem without guessing